# "room for error" replacement word

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the one word that can be used in the place of "room for error", similar to the slang "leash".

For example,

> "Im gonna give you some .... (room for error)"

Comment: 'I'm going to give you some slack' is idiomatic. Merriam Webster does not seem to regard 'slack' in that context as slang. https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/slack

Comment: yeah, that's not what I'm looking for.  There is a more formal word like "levity" or something along that line.

Comment: *rope*, *slack*

Answer (score 4):

I am going to give you some **latitude** in performing these orders. [latitude](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latitude)

```
freedom of action or choice

students are allowed considerable latitude in choosing courses
```

Answer (score 3):

**leeway**

> 1.1 Margin of safety.
>
> ‘there is little leeway if anything goes wrong’
>
> [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/leeway)

Comment: Latitude or leeway are equally good for this context.